# What is the best video live streaming service/API for a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video-streaming, live-streaming

What I'm looking for:

> 1. live streaming video - broadcast, 1:1
> 2. ability to record streams
> 3. up to 10 video streams at the same time

I've tested OpenTok but the quality isn't there for larger videos. Any alternatives or should I write my own?